# map.setCenter and map.Panto will not shift map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maps

I have tried to change the .onchange function multiple times to change map zoom level and center point. Zoom change takes affect, but the map does not change locations.

Any help would be appreciated. I've removed my api key, but otherwise the map will function on its own.

```html
    <script>
    function detectBrowser() {
      var useragent = navigator.userAgent;
      var mapdiv = document.getElementById("map");

      if (useragent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1 || useragent.indexOf('Android') != -1 ) {
        mapdiv.style.width = '100%';
        mapdiv.style.height = '100%';
      } else {
        mapdiv.style.width = '600px';
        mapdiv.style.height = '800px';
      }
    }
      function initMap() {
        var central = {lat: 39.8282, lng: -98.5795};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: central
        });
        var fops = 'http://coleprojects.000webhostapp.com/sqteam.png';
      document.getElementById("FieldTeamMember").onchange = function() {
        map.setZoom(8);
        alert(this.value)
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(this.value));
      };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing location coordinates to google maps as variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676828/passing-location-coordinates-to-google-maps-as-variable)

Comment: Related question: [set coordinates if exist google maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894076/set-coordinates-if-exist-google-maps)

Comment: There is a syntax error in the posted code (missing the closing "}" for initMap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clue in the javascript console:

```
InvalidValueError: in property lat: not a number
```

You need to pass a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) (or [google.maps.LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngLiteral)) to the [map.setCenter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) method:

```
document.getElementById("FieldTeamMember").onchange = function() {
  map.setZoom(8);
  var coords=this.value.split(',');
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
  map.setCenter(latLng);
};
```